# Aggregate data from two tables with different field names

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that each have date and amount fields.  This is for a donation system so one is pledges and the other is donations.  Here are the structure of relevant tables and fields:

**pledges**

- pledge_date
- amount_pledged

**donations**

- processed_date
- amount_donated

I would like to end up with results that sum pledges and donations by month.  Resulting in:

```
Year    Month    Pledged    Donated
2015    01       120        80
2015    02       90         100
2015    05       0          10
2015    06       120        0
```

Obviously it's easy enough to get the data summed and grouped from the tables individually, but is there a way to get it all in one result set?  Here is the sample SQL to get the data just from the pledges table for example:

```
SELECT year(pledge_date) as year, month(pledge_date) as month, sum(amount_pledged) as pledged 
FROM pledges
GROUP by year(pledge_date), month(pledge_date)
ORDER by pledge_date ASC
```

I am trying to accomplish this in MySQL.

Thanks to anyone for your help or clues on how to structure this!

Comment: `JOIN`.  But you need some column(s) that tie the two tables together.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT year, month, sum(pledged) AS Pledged, sum(donated) AS DONATED FROM
(
SELECT year(pledge_date) as year, month(pledge_date) as month, amount_pledged  as pledged, 0 as donated FROM pledges
UNION
SELECT year(processed_date) as year, month(processed_date) as month, 0 as pledged, amount_donated as donated FROM **donations**
)x 
GROUP BY year, month 
ORDER BY year, month
```

Comment: This is the one, perfect once the second SELECT is FROM donations
 (i submitted a fix), 
cheers Keriaki !

Answer (score 0):

`UNION` is your answer

```
SELECT YEAR(p.pledge_date) AS year, MONTH(p.pledge_date) AS month, SUM(p.amount_pledged) AS pledged 
FROM pledges p
UNION 
SELECT YEAR(d.processed_date) AS year, MONTH(d.processed_date) AS month, SUM(d.amount_donated) AS pledged 
FROM donations d
#no need for group
ORDER by year ASC ,month ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Jehad, your answer got me close but I was missing some values from the donation table for some reason.  Anyhow, this seems to give the correct results although I'm not sure it's the most efficient.  I landed on this after learning that MySQL doesn't support full outer joins.

```
SELECT a.pledged, a.year AS year1, a.month AS month1, b.year AS year2, b.month AS month2, b.donated FROM 
( 
SELECT YEAR(pledge_date) AS YEAR, MONTH(pledge_date) AS MONTH, SUM(donation_amt_pledged) AS pledged FROM pledges 
    GROUP BY YEAR(pledge_date), MONTH(pledge_date) 
) a 
RIGHT JOIN 
( 
SELECT YEAR(d.processed_date) AS YEAR, MONTH(d.processed_date) AS MONTH, SUM(d.amount_donated) AS donated FROM donations d
    LEFT JOIN pledges p ON p.id = d.pledge_id 
    GROUP BY YEAR(d.processed_date), MONTH(d.processed_date) 
) b 
ON a.YEAR = b.YEAR AND a.MONTH = b.MONTH 
UNION 
SELECT a.pledged, a.year AS year1, a.month AS month1, b.year AS year2, b.month AS month2, b.donated FROM 
( 
SELECT YEAR(pledge_date) AS YEAR, MONTH(pledge_date) AS MONTH, SUM(donation_amt_pledged) AS pledged FROM pledges 
GROUP BY YEAR(pledge_date), MONTH(pledge_date) 
) a 
LEFT JOIN 
( 
SELECT YEAR(d.processed_date) AS YEAR, MONTH(d.processed_date) AS MONTH, SUM(d.amount_donated) AS donated FROM donations d
    LEFT JOIN pledges p ON p.id = d.pledge_id 
    GROUP BY YEAR(d.processed_date), MONTH(d.processed_date) 
) b 
ON a.YEAR = b.YEAR AND a.MONTH = b.MONTH
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried joining by `YEAR` and `MONTH`?

Try this:

```
SELECT don.donyear AS "Year", don.donmonth AS "Month", ple.plesum "Pledged", don.donsum "Donated" 
FROM 
( 
SELECT YEAR(processed_date) AS "donyear", MONTH(processed_date) AS "donmonth", SUM(amount_donated) "donsum" 
FROM donations 
GROUP BY YEAR(processed_date), MONTH(processed_date) 
) don 
INNER JOIN 
( 
SELECT YEAR(pledge_date) AS "pleyear", MONTH(pledge_date) AS "plemonth", SUM(amount_pledged) AS "plesum" 
FROM pledges 
GROUP BY YEAR(pledge_date), MONTH(pledge_date) 
) ple 
ON don.donyear = ple.pleyear AND don.donmonth = ple.plemonth
ORDER BY don.donyear, don.donmonth ASC;
```